# How can I determine which version of Chrome is installed?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome

I'm working on a WinForms application. I'd like to know if chrome is installed and if so, what version is installed. It is simple enough to see if it is installed. But what is the best way to get the version number programmaticlly?

For other browsers, I call FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo on the main executable. But google doesn't put the version number in the the meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know much about google chrome installs - but it appears to me that the "chrome.exe" is just a shell. The "chrome.dll" appears to be the actual guts and THAT file does have versioning meta data on it.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I've seen thus far is in the registry, but it appears you are limited to the HKEY CURRENT USER node.

On my machine, it's in HKCU\Software\Google\Update\Clients{a guid}\pv

Under the clients node there are a number of guids.  The guid containing the chrome pv key also contains a key called "name" with value of Google Chrome.

So you might need to iterate through the guid nodes under that Clients node until you find one with key "name" = "Google Chrome" and then look for the value of the pv key.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome, go to the wrench (tools), highlight About Chrome, and the version number is right there.
Jeff

Comment: That works to see the version manually, but I need to get the version number programmaticlly.